# What's the point of first stringers?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

You can select a handful of "elite" palicos to be in your first stringer squad, but you can only bring one with you as a sub and the first stringers can't go on meownster hunter missions...

What is the benefit/point of setting more than 1 first stringer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first stringers determine the skills your Main Palico will have. 2 First Stringers with the same Forte will give your main Palico  the first tier ability of that Forte, 3 of the same type will give you the second tier ability of that forte, 4 of the same type will give you the third tier, and 5 of the same type will give your main Palico a special ability only he/she will have access to.

For example, suppose you have five first stringers, two Healting and three Combat. Your main palico would then have access to Health Horn, Demon Horn, and Piercing Boomerang.  The Health Horn comes from the two Healing Palicos, and the Demon Horn and Piercing Boomerangs comes from the Combat Palicos.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the only way to have the Leadership forte on your main palico is by having a maximum of any two fortes in the first ringers. For example, I have two attack, two healing, and one defense, so my main palico gets demon horn and healing horn but still keeps his leadership abilities.