# How do I change my main palicos forte?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

My main palico had the leadership forte when I started out, but I noticed that he currently has the healing forte. How did this happen? Is this caused by my full team of healing 1st stringers?

How can I change it back? Can I change it to anything I want?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207666/whats-the-point-of-first-stringers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Ace Palico's Forte is affected by the number of 1st Stringers of a specific type. You can change it back by reducing the number of Healing 1st Stringers and change it to anything else by designating enough Palicoes of one type as 1st Stringers.